# Java regex pattern issue

Tags: java, regex

I have a string:

```
bundle://24.0:0/com/keop/temp/Activator.class
```

And from this string I need to get `com/keop/temp/Activator` but the following pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("bundle://.*/(.*)\\.class");
```

returns only `Activator`. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the initial token `.*` with `?` for a [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) match.

```
bundle://.*?/(.*)\\.class
           ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex uses greedy matching with a `.` that matches *any* character (but a newline). `.*/` reads everything up to the final `/`, `(.*)\\.` matches everything up to the final period. Instead of lazy matching, you can restrict the characters matched to non-`/` before the string you want to match. Change to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("bundle://[^/]*/(.*)\\.class");
```

Sample code:

```
String str = "bundle://24.0:0/com/keop/temp/Activator.class";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("bundle://[^/]*/(.*)\\.class");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Output of the [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ2VYRUhZMzNRWjQ):

```
com/keop/temp/Activator
```